# I'm looking for a 'dragon riders academy' book series

Tags: story-identification, novel

On the cover there was a boy and a girl (or at least one had long and one had short hair). They had armor similar to Hiccup in the *How to Train Your Dragon* movie and the background is a castle(?)

Answer (score 2):

Could this be [*Stonebriar Academy - School for Dragon Riders*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/60758635-stonebriar-academy---school-for-dragon-riders)? The fifth book in the series (prosaically named *'Book 5'*) has the male and female characters set against a castle.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably too different from your description to be your book, but I'll post it just in case. Could it be the [Rise of the Dragon Master series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/347867-rise-of-the-dragon-master) by Stephany Wallace? A couple of the books have a man and woman in front of a castle:

[image: Dragon Rider]

It isn't an academy or school, though the protagonist *Braxton* is training to be a dragon rider.

Comment: No sorry, also don't take this seriously but i literally laughed at the book not what's written but because of the cover it like the whole story told there

Comment: @MariaZapata Oh well, if you got a laugh out of it the answer wasn't completely wasted :-)